# Register Multiple Sip client accounts on same client PC and same server

Tags: sip

```
var registrationRequired = true;
            var userName = "4000";
            var displayName = "4000";
            var authenticationId = "4000";
            var registerPassword = "4000";
            var domainHost = "host";
            var domainPort = 5060;

            var account = new SIPAccount(registrationRequired, displayName, userName, authenticationId, registerPassword, domainHost, domainPort);
```

I'm using Ozeki SIP SDK and this code works. Problem is, when I want to have multiple accounts on same PC, like 4001,4002,4003,4004... (multiple app instances), last registered account unregisters others.

Is there any way to have more than one clients logged in?

Comment: how are you doing the multiple registrations? if you're using the SAME `account` var for each one, then you're killing the previous objects by overwriting the var with the new one.

Comment: @MarcB I hardcoded parameters for example, I want to register with multiple instances of app with different logins (to same host).